# Catch vertical scroll event using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to catch vertical scroll event of a div using jquery .
I used :

```
$("#scrollDiv").on('scroll', function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

But it catches all scrolls . How do i catch only the vertical scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I got it !!
For anyone who still having a trouble : 
1. Make the div overflow as none
2. Give the div a height and a width 
3. The above code 
It will work .

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event doesn't contain information about the scroll direction/axis, but the actual scroll position is always stored as property of the scrollable container. You have to cache that value somewhere(e.g. with $.data() directly on the element) and compare it on scroll to the new scroll position. As you asked for vertical scroll, you must check the `scrollTop` - property, for horizontal scroll go with `scrollLeft`.

```
$('#scrollDiv').on('scroll', function(e){

    var target = $(e.target);

    if(target.data('stored_scroll_top') == 'undefined') {
        target.data( 'stored_scroll_top', 0);
    }

    if (target.data('stored_scroll_top') != e.target.scrollTop) {
        alert('hi');
        target.data( 'stored_scroll_top', e.target.scrollTop);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add other two data properties to your div:

- horizontal: the previous scrollLeft value
- vertical: the previous scrollTop value

On scrolling you may compare these values and decide which scroll happened.

In this way you know also the amount of scrolling. If, instead, you are interested only in which one happened you may use only one variable.

The snippet:

```js
$("#scrollDiv").data('horizontal', 0).data('vertical', 0).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var horizontal = $(this).data('horizontal');
    var vertical = $(this).data('vertical');
    var cHorizontal = this.scrollLeft;
    var cVertical = this.scrollTop;
    $(this).data('horizontal', cHorizontal);
    $(this).data('vertical', cVertical);
    if (horizontal != cHorizontal) {
        console.log('Horizontal scroll.....');
    }
    if (vertical != cVertical) {
        console.log('Vertical scroll.....');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="scrollDiv" style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px;height: 200px;white-space: nowrap;">
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
    This is a div element.......................................<br/>
</div>
```